# Is this sentence in the passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

I'm having a discussion with someone and we are having a few disagreements over whether this sentence is passive voice or not:

***"I was scared by the noise."***

We've discussed linking verbs, whether "scared" is an adjective or not, whether it is the past participle in the active voice, etc.

So, is that sentence in the passive voice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In itself the construction [*BE* + past participle of a transitive verb] is often ambiguous: it can be read as either

> a passive construction, in which *BE* is the passive auxiliary, or
>   a copulation, in which *BE* is the ordinary copula (linking verb) and the past participle acts as an ascriptive adjective

Consequently the bare statement *I was scared* could be read as either narration of an event in passive voice or a description of your state of mind.

But in your sentence the construction is followed by a *by* phrase designating an Agent, *the noise*. You have made it explicit that something 'performed' the action of scaring you; consequently *I was scared* has to be taken as a passive.

Comment: I'd never really thought about this one before. My instinctive default interpretation of *I was **scared / frightened / shocked / embarrassed / etc*** as "adjectival" is so strong I find it quite hard to imagine using them reflecting a "passive" usage. But you're quite right that syntactically it's all pretty clear-cut (or ambiguous, as the case may be! :) Is there an easy way to summarize *why* passive is an unlikely interpretation for examples like mine?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm, good question. Off the top of my head: the passive is implicitly perfective and telic and implies a resulting state--(indeed that seems to me very likely why we construct the passive with the copula). With a bare copula (*I was scared*, *John was killed*, *Dinner is served*) there is nothing to put the focus--the 'new information'--on the performance of the action, so the focus is on its outcome. ... And if all that sounds a lot like my description of the perfect, well, yeah, they seem to be closely related--by the PaPpl, if nothing else.

Comment: Contrasting *I was scared / I felt scared*, it seems to me they're semantically equivalent so long as we discard the highly unlikely "passive" interpretation (which I really can't make work with the ***felt*** version). But they certainly don't seem to be equivalent with ***I was robbed / I felt robbed***.

Comment: (Where I can get my head around *We wuz robbed, so it's not surprising we **felt** robbed*.)

Comment: ...can't resist saying that it amuses me to discover the orthography [***We wuz robbed** outranks **We was robbed***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=We+was+robbed%2CWe+wuz+robbed&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWe%20was%20robbed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWe%20wuz%20robbed%3B%2Cc0) in Google NGrams.

Comment: @FumbleFingers More interesting questions! ... It occurs to me that we've got a different sort of 'Patient' with *rob* than with *scare*. With *scare* the Patient is directly affected by the action; with *rob*, what's directly affected is actually the goods taken, expressed with an oblique, *of [goods]*, and the person robbed, syntactically a DO, is semantically a kind of IO. I'm gonna hafta read up on this. <sigh> *pushing it onto the stack* </sigh>

Comment: I guess I was just so taken with your lucid & concise summary of the factors relevant to OP's *precise* context I kinda took it for granted there would be (one or more) fairly simple principles governing closely-related usages. Not only that, I kinda took it for granted *you personally* would be likely to be consciously aware of any such principles. Me, I might be able to interpret actual examples according to "principles", but usually I don't consciously know what those principles are, so I couldn't possibly hope to articulate them.